# How to add Azure Application Insights for multiple environments to Angular?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to add application insights to an Angular app for three environments: DEV, UAT, and PROD. Each has its own unique instrumentation key. I'm trying to follow the steps in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-angular-plugin. However, this article only showed how to add one instrumentation key. It doesn't specify how I could change the instrumentation key dynamically based on the specific environment(dev, uat, prod). Any thoughts on how I could achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: just use the corresponding environment.ts file for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the path where you can define your instrumentation key

```
   config: {
            instrumentationKey: this.appConfig.insights.instrumentationKey,
            extensions: [this.angularPlugin],
            extensionConfig: {
                [this.angularPlugin.identifier]: {
                    router: this.router,
                },
```

and you can check the related discussions from the below articles

https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/configuring-azure-application-insights-in-an-angular-application#configure-application-insights-with-the-angular-plugin

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-add-application-insights-to-an-angular-spa/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-integrate-azure-application-insights-service-to-an-angular-application/